# Unit testing middleware after express-validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs, express-validator

I have my routes.js like

```
app.get('/', userRules(), validate, mycontroller)
```

```
const { query } = require('express-validator');

module.exports = {
  userRules: () => [query('team_id').optional().isInt(),
    query('active_team').optional().isBoolean()],
};
```

and my validate function looks like

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const { createMessage } = require('../helpers/index');
module.exports = {
  validate: (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      const message = createMessage(errors.array());
      return res.status(400).json({ error: true, message });
    }
    return next();
  },
}
```

What I want to achieve is to UnitTest that validate function in order to understand the behaviour

```
const httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http');
const { userRules } = require('../../router/validation');
const { validateUsers } = require('../index');
    it('should return a 400', () => {
      const req = httpMocks.createRequest({
        query: {
          active_team: 'aaaa',
        },
      });
      myStub(req, userRules());
      const res = httpMocks.createResponse();
      validateUsers(req, res, next);
      expect(res.statusCode).toBe(400);
    });
```

What I'm expecting is a 400 but I got a 200 and the next() function is getting called everytime

Is there any way to do this?
I know I can use supertest but I don't really want it.

Comment: any solution for this yet :) ?